# TypeError when trying to sort dict keys

Tags: python

I'm learning to work with dicts and have one that is structured like this:

```
DATA = {
    'ATL': {
        '2019': {
            'status': 'inactive',
            'abbr': 'ATL',
            'city': 'Atlanta'},
        '2016': {
            'status': 'active',
            'abbr': 'ATL',
            'city': 'Atlanta'},
        '2018': {
            'status': 'inactive',
            'abbr': 'ATL',
            'city': 'Atlanta'},
        '2017': {
            'status': 'active',
            'abbr': 'ATL',
            'city': 'Atlanta'}
        }
    }
```

Here is one attempt at sorting by year:

```
sorted_keys = sorted(DATA['ATL'].keys())
```

Every time I get `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'`. When I print the keys it only returns the years which would I would assume are viewed as 'int', right? Since I'm fairly new to using dicts I'm well aware that there could be a problem with the structure of the dict but am pretty much stuck. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `print(sorted(DATA.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))` ?

Comment: For which part of code you got `TypeError`? Can you add it into question?

Comment: Are some of your keys integers?

Comment: The posted code & data does not produce the error described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly note that if you want to sort the actual dictionary by keys you want to feed `sorted` the entire dictionary, not just the keys.

`DATA.items()` will be returning `key`/`value` tuples. In such case you must specify under which criteria you want to sort. For that you can use the `key` argument in `sorted`:

```
dict(sorted(DATA['ATL'].items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0])))

{'2016': {'status': 'active', 'abbr': 'ATL', 'city': 'Atlanta'},
 '2017': {'status': 'active', 'abbr': 'ATL', 'city': 'Atlanta'},
 '2018': {'status': 'inactive', 'abbr': 'ATL', 'city': 'Atlanta'},
 '2019': {'status': 'inactive', 'abbr': 'ATL', 'city': 'Atlanta'}}
```

---

Also note that it is advisable to cast to `int`, otherwise the sorting process will be lexicographical, which might not be an issue in this case, but it is usually safer to do so (not sure what range of years you're dealing with here, but sorting lexicographically would produce unexpected results such as 950 > 2019)

This will also prevent from the error you're obtaining, which seems to be produced by the fact of having a mixture of data types in the keys.

Comment: If it might not be an issue, why *must* the years be cast to `int`?

Comment: As mentioned the main reason is to avoid the error OP is getting due to the mixed types @ScottHunter I guess its also nice for op to know that it can cause issues in the general case (although indeed it that where the only reason it is not necessary here), as for instance (999 will be greater than say 2019). But here the main reason I see is that it should get rid of the error

Comment: "Good idea" <> "must".

Comment: And the posted code does not exhibit the error described.

Comment: Yes yes I agree @ScottHunter But as mentioned, it should solve OPs error which is causes by having mixed data types in the keys, right?

Comment: Yes that is clear enough, but it seems quite obvious that the only explanation for this error is that some keys are integers @scott

Comment: Actually giving it some better though we have no idea what range of years OP is dealing with so indeed it is safer to cast to integer @ScottHunter As mentioned in the update, not doing so could produce unexpected results such as 950 > 2019)

Comment: One last time: "must".

Comment: haha okay @ScottHunter :)) Got rid of that must... good talk :DD

Comment: So I'm just now getting back to this. Couple things: @scottHunter - I have no idea what I did differently but now the script does return the years

Comment: @yatu you correctly interpreted that I was looking to sort the dict, should've made that clear. Your script got the job done and it makes me feel a bit better that one of my other attempts was somewhat close to being right. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I followed your example and after using a dictionary of

```
DATA = {'ATL': {'2016': {'abbr': 'ATL', 'city': 'Atlanta', 'status': 'active'},
  '2017': {'abbr': 'ATL', 'city': 'Atlanta', 'status': 'active'},
  '2018': {'abbr': 'ATL', 'city': 'Atlanta', 'status': 'inactive'},
  '2019': {'abbr': 'ATL', 'city': 'Atlanta', 'status': 'inactive'}}}
```

And sorting

```
sorted_keys = sorted(DATA['ATL'].keys())
```

The output of sorted_keys is

```
['2016', '2017', '2018', '2019']
```

Which appears to be what you want. The problem is, you must notice that the years are actually strings, not integers. So if you want to have a list of the years in integer format you could do the following

```
nums = [int(year) for year in sorted_keys]
```

This would give you a list of the years in integer form that wouldn't raise a TypeError exception.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the keys to integers:

```py
sorted_keys = sorted([int(i) for i in DATA['ATL'].keys()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct. I tried the following.

Used this as input.

```
DATA = {
'ATL': {
    '2019': {
        'status': 'inactive',
        'abbr': 'ATL',
        'city': 'Atlanta'},
    '2016': {
        'status': 'active',
        'abbr': 'ATL',
        'city': 'Atlanta'},
    '2018': {
        'status': 'inactive',
        'abbr': 'ATL',
        'city': 'Atlanta'},
    '2017': {
        'status': 'active',
        'abbr': 'ATL',
        'city': 'Atlanta'}
    }
}
```

Executed your code.

```
sorted_keys = sorted(DATA['ATL'].keys())
sorted_keys
```

I got the following output

```
['2016', '2017', '2018', '2019']
```

Maybe you have some other line of code giving the error?

This should work if you just want to output the keys in a sorted way. But if you want your dictionary to be sorted, it will not work. `dict` cannot preserve order. You will have to use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).